# Share point 2010 case study project for learning

Tags: sharepoint, case

I come from asp.net , SQL server experience of 7 years. I  am learning share point 2010 during my free time . At work I don't have the opportunity to work on share point but I would like to expand my skill set with sp2010. Can anyone provide me a good link to develop a share point site with some case study ...?????

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news: SharePoint is huge :)

I would recommend a book more than a link: [SharePoint 2010 Development with Visual Studio 2010 (Microsoft .NET Development Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321718313). This book assumes you have zero knowledge of SharePoint, but some .NET/ASP.NET experience, which seems to be your case. It explains everything very clear and at slow pace and it also has examples to put in practice the stuff you learn.

You will need a 64 bits system with Windows Server 2008 or Windows 7, at least 4 GB of RAM and VS2010.

Good luck!